# Prove that this derivative does not exist

Tags: derivatives

Can you prove rigorously (using the definition of limits) that the derivative of $|x-2|$ is undefined at $2$.

I did for $|x|$ at $x=0$. I am a bit confused about how to deal with limits at values other than zero. $|x|$ was easy because $\Delta x$  was also equal to $0$. Here $\Delta x$ should be equal to zero but $x$ should be equal to $2$. Right? I know this is confusing, because I am confused a bit.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the derivate of a function $f$ evaluated at the point $x=a$ is:
$$f’(a)=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$ In this caso $f(x):=|x-2|$ and so $f(2)=0$. Hence $$f’(2)=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{|x-2|}{x-2}.$$ This limit doesn’t exist since it is equal to $1$ when $x \to 2^+$ and it is equal to $-1$ when $x \to 2^-$.